# Difference in x/2 and x>>1 or x*2 and x << 1 where x is an integer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, multiplication, integer-division

As we know for calculating an integer x/2 we just write`y=x/2;`similarly for x*2; but good programmers use bit manipulation to calculate this.

They just do `y = x >> 1;`

Is there any difference between these two method at all? 
By difference I mean difference in time/space/memory required or both are exactly the same (i.e x/2 is implemented by x >> 1)?

Also are multiplication/division with other numbers instead of 2 implemented the same way (i.e. `5*5 = 10*2 + 5*1 = 10 << 1 + 5 = 25`)?

Comment: No, good programmers do not use bit manipulation to do that, only bad ones, or possibly programmers working with with ancient or esoteric compilers

Comment: Depends on how smart the compiler is... e.g. on an original 8086 cpu, imul was 128-154 cycles, and down to 3 on  core i5. If the compiler wasn't smart enough to rewrite a `* 2` operate as a bitshift, then doing it yourself would save a huge amount of cycles. these days, not so much.

Comment: doesn't it should have depends on implementation of language.

Comment: If you can use that trick in code it means that the factor is a compile time constant, if it is a compile time constant, your compiler knows about it. The compiler also knows your platform, probably better than you... let it do its job

Comment: _"good programmers use bit manipulation"_ - bullpuckey!

Comment: **Good programmers don't do that.** I know it was said before, but it has to be said again and again until this belief that ugly code is faster or better dies out.

Comment: In C++, for signed integers, *2 is faster than <<1. That is because when n is positive, n*2 is known to be positive (overflow is undefined), while n<<1 can be negative. (and they generate the same asm)

Comment: There's some small chance that the bit-manipulation code actually is faster if your "integer" has signed type, and you happen to know that it has non-negative value. That usually still doesn't add up to a good reason to do it, though.

Comment: Many eons ago, "good" programmers did that.  This was back in the age of steam-powered computers, though.  Any modern compiler knows how to optimize a literal multipier/divisor better than you do, and "good" programmers know they should let compilers do what they do best.

Comment: @nos seriously guys! i always thought of that good programmers uses bit manipulation lot.

Comment: Good programmers use their tools _effectively_. Manually using bit manipulation as a form of optimization for this scenario is no longer necessary and would be an ineffective use of our tools.

Comment: But in some cases using bit manipulation shows real cleverness.

Comment: The point of programming is not to "show cleverness".  The point of program is to perform the task at hand, do it reliably, do it in a way that can be maintained, and, as much as anything, do it quickly, since there's always something else that needs doing far more than "cleverly" optimizing minor computations.

Comment: @i_m_optional: Bad programmers aspire to cleverness; good programmers aspire to simplicity.

Comment: @MikeSeymour A misconception is clear today :)

Comment: It's not about good/bad programmers it's more about the architecture/compiler you are working with and how experienced you are with these two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question has been answered on the ridiculousfishblog : http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/will-it-optimize.html

> 5. Division by 2 to right shift
>
> Will GCC transform an integer division by 2 to a right shift?

```
int halve_it(int x) {
   return x / 2;
}

int halve_it(int x) {
   return x >> 1;
}
```

> The right shift operator is equivalent to division that rounds towards
>   negative infinity, but normal division rounds towards zero. Thus the
>   proposed optimization will produce the wrong result for odd negative
>   numbers.
>
> The result can be "fixed up" by adding the most significant bit to the
>   numerator before shifting, and gcc does this.

Good programers let compilers optimize their code, unless they hit a performance penalty.

**EDIT :** Since you ask for official sources, let's quote the standard rationale document for C99. You find it here : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

> In C89, division of integers involving negative operands could round upward or downward in an implementation-defined manner; the intent was to avoid incurring overhead in run-time code to check for special cases and enforce specific behavior. In Fortran, however, the result will always truncate toward zero, and the overhead seems to be acceptable to the numeric programming community. Therefore, C99 now requires similar behavior, which should facilitate porting of code from Fortran to C. The table in §7.20.6.2 of this document illustrates the required semantics.

Your optimization would have been correct in C89, since it let to the compiler to do as it wants. However, C99 introduce a new convention to comply with Fortran code. Here is an example of what is expected of the divide operator (always from the same document) :

[image]

Unfortunately your optimization does not comply with the C99 standard, since it does not give the right result for x = -1 :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int div8(int x)
{
    return x/3;
}

int rs8( int x )
{
    return x >> 3;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    volatile int x = -1;
    printf("div : %d \n", div8(x) );
    printf("rs : %d \n", rs8(x) );

    return 0;
}

Result:
div : 0 
rs : -1 
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

If you look at the compiled code, you can spot an interesting difference (compiled with g++ v4.6.2) :

```
0040138c <__Z4div8i>:
  40138c:   55                      push   %ebp
  40138d:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  40138f:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  401392:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  401394:   79 03                   jns    401399 <__Z4div8i+0xd>
  401396:   83 c0 0f                add    $0x7,%eax
  401399:   c1 f8 04                sar    $0x3,%eax
  40139c:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  40139d:   c3                      ret    

0040139e <__Z3rs8i>:
  40139e:   55                      push   %ebp
  40139f:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  4013a1:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  4013a4:   c1 f8 03                sar    $0x3,%eax
  4013a7:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  4013a8:   c3                      ret
```

line `401392`, there is a `test` instruction, which will check the parity bit and, if the number is negative, will add `1 << (n-1) = 7` to x before right-shifting by 3 units.

Comment: @i_m_optional : Added standard rationale if you're interested.

Comment: Description level: GOD !

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/34hare689 shows non-debug builds.  GCC and clang make branchless asm for `x/8`, using `cmov` to select between `x>>3` or `(x+7)>>3`.  Or with older clang, more shifting bithack stuff.  Note that with `unsigned` integers, division by a power of 2 really is just a right shift.

Answer (score 8):

You should code what you *mean*, and optimize when you need to do it.

As far as I know, the difference is for signed numbers, where the behavior is undefined. This is likely historical due to the fact that other signbit mechanisms existed than 2's compliment, but in effect that means compilers can use instructions that may not behave how you expect when optimizing.

Comment: Which one is undefined?

Comment: Signed negative numbers have undefined behavior with shifting.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

In general, bit manipulation is faster than arithmetic, especially multiplication and division.  However, many—if not most—optimizing compilers will do the right thing for speed so it does not matter which is written.

The 1978 Pascal compiler for the CDC Cyber generated code to shift and add for multiplies which involved a constant with 1 or 2 bits.  For example:

```
 x := somevar * 10;    /* 10 has two bits set */
```

would generate code equivalent to

```
 x := (somevar << 1) + (somevar << 3);   /*  *2 + *8 */
```

This was substantially faster on a Cyber than using the integer multiply instruction.

Comment: but what about current compilers like gcc on more faster cpu like i7 or i5

Comment: @i_m_optional:  I doubt recent CPUs have the same characteristics, mostly because the CDC is so different architecturally.  Though it is rather like a Cray:  could be that `gcc` compiling code for a Cray would do similar transformations.

Answer (score 1):

As per nos, good programmers do not shift instead of multiplying and dividing: even when it does the same thing, it's no faster and more arcane.

Also it doesn't always do the same thing.

Whether shift right is arithmetic or logical depends on your CPU architecture: C allows either. So `-23 >> 1` is permitted to give a positive result.

Answer (score 1):

`x/2` is not equal to `x >> 1` for negative numbers. Anyway, practically every compiler will replace multiplication or division by the power of two to bit manipulation automatically if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The entire premise of this question smells of a premature micro-optimization.

When you are writing code, you write it to be clear.  If you are multiplying by a number, show the operation as multiplication.

The exception comes when/if a performance barrier is hit and it is determined (through profiling) that your code needs to be adjusted to an "uglier" version (e.g. using bitshifts instead of multiplication and division).  Unless you have run into such a performance issue (not likely), there is no reason to use bitshifts when you mean to use multiplication (or division).

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation of expressions depends on the processor architecture, platform architecture and the compiler.

In theory, `x >> 1` is the same as `x / 2`, for all unsigned integers.
If the compiler is smart enough or the optimizations are set correctly, the compiler should generate the same executable code for each, provided your process has shift operations.

Also, `x << 1` and `x * 2` should be the same for all unsigned integers.

Some compilers may not recognize the same and actually perform multiplication for `x * 2` and division for `x / 2`.

The truth will be in the assembly language generated by your compiler.

The bigger issue is in **readability**.  Most people are familiar with multiplication as it is taught early in schools.  Binary shifting is not common to most people.  I still get questioned by programmers about the shift operations.  When in doubt, choose readability over performance.

Comment: Yes, compilers like GCC and Clang do reliably turn `x/2` into a right shift for unsigned types, and `x*2` into left shift for signed or unsigned.  (And multiple instructions including a right shift for signed division.)  And yes, if the semantic meaning is arithmetic, use a multiply or divide.  If the semantic meaning is moving bits around in a bitfield or mask, use a shift.  (e.g. when you're going to `&` or `|` the result)

Answer (score 0):

CPU get a logic circuit to multiply numbers, in intel x86 it is MUL instruction.
Good programmer do code like this and wrap the whole thing decently.

But you surely missing the logic for checking overflow by assuming x<1 = x*2, and it works only on unsigned integer. You cannot divide and multiply a negative number by x>1 or x<1, because the rightmost bit is the bit for +/-.

Answer (score 0):

Let me demonstrate on an example:

```
int f(int n){
  if(n<=0) return 33;
  if((n*2)<=0) return 42;
  return 0;
}
int g(int n){
  if(n<=0) return 33;
  if((n<<1)<=0) return 42;
  return 0;
}
```

You might assume that both functions do the same thing. However, let us look at the generated asm for f:

```
testl   %edi, %edi
movl    $0, %edx
movl    $33, %eax
cmovg   %edx, %eax
ret
```

and g:

```
testl   %edi, %edi
movl    $33, %eax
jle .L5
addl    %edi, %edi
movl    $0, %edx
movb    $42, %al
testl   %edi, %edi
cmovg   %edx, %eax
.L5:
rep ret
```

As you notice, the compiler was able to remove the second comparison for f but not for g. The reason is that signed multiplication may not overflow while bit operations may. Trying to be clever made your code slower. By the way, note that the compiler found it clever to replace n<<1 with n+n...

Comment: Hold on, signed multiplication may not overflow? Well that's one way to interpret the UB-ness of it I guess, but it applies equally to signed left shifts.

Comment: Which compiler and optimization level is this?

Comment: @harold no, it doesn't apply to left shift in C++11.

Comment: @wallyk Clang and GCC both do this. ICC does not.

Comment: @wallyk g++ -O2 or -O3.

Comment: @MarcGlisse well, finally some sanity in C++11 then. What behaviour do they specify now? Wrapping modulo a power of two? Honestly though, all this shows is that broken code is broken. The code with the multiply isn't better, it's incorrect.

Comment: @harold I wouldn't call the following for E1 << E2 sanity: "if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value".

Comment: @MarcGlisse oh, ok. Yes, still not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

For x86 architectures, considering compilers like gcc or VS the difference is not that obvious; actually some programmers would consider **using >> or << instead of / or * a form of obfuscation.**

**The difference becomes apparent for embedded systems** where you have different architectures and compilers. It all comes down to what instructions are available on a particular architecture and how smart the compiler is.

Let me elaborate: 
what are the things you need to consider for any operation `a op b` ? well the very minimum you should consider the data type of the operands and of the result. Why is that important? Because integer numbers are represented differently than decimal numbers and of course there is the matter of overflow ( 16bit * 16 bit = 32 bit usually). 
Let's take multiplication: on some architectures you have instructions for multiplications for several operands like:

```
  16 bit * 16 bit = 32 bit
  16 bit * 16 bit = 16 bit
  16 bit * 32 bit = 32 bit
  ....
```

Depending on how you write your code and how smart the compiler is the generated code will consist of a certain number of instructions (the smaller this number, the faster the code executes).

So far the same is true for both *,/ and >>,<<.

Multiplication is usually supported in the hardware and you have one instruction to get the result (unless you are dealing with data types which the architecture does not support natively and the instruction has to be emulated - but that is more complicated).
Division however is more expensive and is usually emulated: successive subtractions in a repetitive loop. Thus a lot more instructions to get the result.

Some compilers are smart enough and analyze the code, generating shift operations for division/ multiplication  with an immediate value power of two; but writing code like `a=2; c= b*a;` can put even the smartest compiler in a difficult position.

Shift on the other hand is more straight forward: you are guaranteed to have the instruction supported and usually the result is the same size as the operand ( 16bi >> 1 = 16bit).

Considering all of that, you are usually helping the compile generate better, faster code when you use shift operations instead of multiplication/division