# Divide by variable power of 2 using assembly

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86-64, bit-shift, integer-division

I've got this task:

> ###### dividePower2
>
> Compute *x*/2<sup>*n*</sup>, for 0 ≤ *n* ≤ 30. Round toward zero.
>
> - Argument 1: `x`
> - Argument 2: `n`
>
> Examples:
>
> - `dividePower2(15,1) = 7`
> - `dividePower2(-33,4) = -2`

This is what I've got so far but I don't know if I'm heading in the right direction (AT&T syntax required):

```
.global dividePower2
   dividePower2:
   sar $2, %esi
   ret
```

Comment: Right direction, yes, but functions normally return in EAX.  And the first arg is in EDI, if this is x86-64 System V; the second arg (shift count) is in ESI.  Also, note that arithmetic right shift rounds towards -Infinity, not zero.  So you need to adjust by one depending on the sign bit.  (Compilers can make working asm for you, e.g. look at `gcc -O2` output on https://godbolt.org/.  [Difference in x/2 and x>>1 or x\*2 and x << 1 where x is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21533119) shows compiler-generated asm for division by 2, but only from a debug build)

Comment: `2 >> n` will calculate `1/(2^(n-1))`, not what you want. You don't need to calculate `2^n` separately at all.

Comment: @dimich: Huh?  This is AT&T syntax.  This is doing `n >>= 2;`.  Maybe you're right, though, maybe they thought they were doing `2 >> n` or something?  Probably I shouldn't have said "right direction"; I assumed they were starting with a hard-coded `n` of 2 as a test case, and were going to make the count variable later.  But that might not be what they think this instruction does.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, indeed, first operand is count of bits to shift. Anyway, OP don't need to shift a constant nor a fixed number of bits. If there were no requirement for *round toward zero*, the solution would be just `x >> n`.

Comment: @dimich: the efficient way to do this *is* with a bit-shift.  For non-negative `x`, just `x>>n`.  For negative `x`, `x / (1<<n)` == `(x + (1<<n)-1 ) >> n`.  e.g. `x/8 = (x+7) >> 3` for negative `x`, like compilers do for constant powers of 2.  https://godbolt.org/z/4v85YM8nb (with lea+cmov, or older clang broadcasts the sign bit then logical right shifts by 32-n to get 2^n - 1 (negative) or 0 (non-negative).  Unfortunately GCC and Clang miss this optimization for variable `n` with a `1<<n` divisor, even when they know `n` is in the 0..30 range.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, this problem can and should be solved with bit-shift efficiently. Good idea to shift `1` for negative argument compensation!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, an arithmetic right shift is a useful part of this if you're going to do it efficiently.
But no, `n >>= 2;` is not a useful thing to do.  Any shifting you do needs to be variable-count (or by 31 if you're broadcasting the sign bit to make a 0 / -1 mask).

Look at how compilers handle a constant `n` like `return x / (1<<11);` for example.  ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgDMpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHKEEANT8qBAbm6qkm/sMcyYA7FYaAIIA9ABUJjebL5u3t5sAbmJemAC0xEMwEwxwY/E26FQmAUDDAHC2CEwtCSmzQLCSdFiCk2qCSjhYeAAXiCCAg8NiiJttF4FFsFGSqARsSBbk9rq9jlRNhAGCZ4th4hpNhc3CLNrz4m4NGdLmyORziJgCMsGJsNHyruzXhcACJs%2B6s56vRXK4iq1RvblcPmiyWnDVs3WOm77KINPaCA4yzUKpUqg63CDWyU2rhcM7xTW6jgLWicACsvD8HC0pFQnFFlmsmwUSxWIPM8R4pAImhjCwA1iB4gAOAB0AE4GwA2BvneLNsztsy1szx/ScSRJstpzi8BQgDQlssLOCwGBQBcQJBojH0MgUCCrzFxYAVAJYT54VYANTwmAA7gB5JKMTjFmi0AhYyhREdRUINACe994H%2BYxBfleUTaNUpbcLwaJsIIV4MLQP4prwWBRF4wBuGItAThBpBYCwQLiIhOF4IqNSfNCI6YKo1ReM%2Bv7kIISJ0bQeBRICgEeFgI4EMQeAsL%2BCxUAYwAKGel43ne2H8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOohG6Fw%2BhAig1jWPoLETpACy4o4AhYX8V7xJsfwAOoYbwqBkcQPFYPpEALO0xl%2BBArijH46nBFMJRlHoKRpB5PnBfkHm9IFsy2EiYG1BM4Xqe5iXdNF/TlEM3TJdljQZTM5RuXmqwSLGCbDoR6YcAcNbNn8zaSJswDIMgmwVHWZjcrghAkMKPbhrw4FaHMlYgPGU5xhwQ6kHxjV1h2kg1vEZhcKtNaSFI5ykMmqbVeOk7Tohs5LiuqDoju5CUNu64oAYRgTQemBHqe57XreyYPnQz7EBOEBvoR/7fnRQOAcBoEOHRUGMAQsHwSOyGoehtCYXRuH4Wsqb4CRjhkVhqaUdRtHYRsjHYcxrHfhxmNDTxfEQQJQkiW94mfbwUnCKI4jyRzSlqCOugBPdxjaZYulRC5hl4hkpnmZZNko3ZDlOeRBlxfYHkuAw7ieC0ej%2BcUmURaFGS5SFBQMAVQUpfFHQMF0Iy6zkNsa2l%2BUBUbKVJU7vl5ZMhuFWVizLKV4YDhwiY7SO1W1fVjWosLmzxnWGidd1%2BBEMQ/VFnMQ0zmNE3hzNu12WOtiHcN5bh2YvB8eckh1lI8SCutGjNjW8bxP2JejhwefHaQc6ICASwEEkNFXVu51rrE4SsGsqh1Q1TUtW1HU14EGckHg6B6BzMnc9IvNKPzql6BegJJPx4eRz31VXjR49bKgXKL3HK%2Bte18RpxAHgXeu2dBpHRGgsRETAsBxFckXWu/hk4d2bK2c4NYuANiLJIRqiQ75lwnFOSuo1SBVmbFwFOGgW7NniOcMwzZzhEJrOHeIlU9plzweVDgG8sF92AVXByaRnCSCAA)).

```
# x86-64 GCC -O3
bar(int):
        testl   %edi, %edi        # set FLAGS according to x
        leal    2047(%rdi), %eax
        cmovns  %edi, %eax        # x < 0  ?  x+(1<<11)-1  :  x
        sarl    $11, %eax         # arithmetic right shift that value
        ret                       # return value in EAX
```

**A simple `x >> n` (`sar %cl, %edi`) rounds towards -Infinity, rather than truncating toward 0.**  *[Difference in x/2 and x>>1 or x*2 and x << 1 where x is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533119/difference-in-x-2-and-x1-or-x2-and-x-1-where-x-is-an-integer)* goes into the details of how compilers implement C division semantics for `x/2` or `x/8` or whatever.

Adding `2047` can wrap small negative numbers into small positive numbers, but only numbers less than 1<<11.  So the later `sar` will shift all the set bits out and leave `0`, like we want for division with truncation toward zero for the original small negative number with magnitude smaller than 2048.

For larger-magnitude negative numbers, adding a positive number decreases the magnitude, decreasing the quotient unless it was an exact multiple to start with.  (Since we're adding 1 less than the divisor).  This lets us use `sar` (arithmetic right shift) which rounds towards -Infinity, accounting for the off-by-1 difference between it and what we want for truncating division.

---

For a variable count, `return x / (1<<n)`, compilers naively just materialize the `1<<n` and use `idiv`.  But we can do better by following the same pattern as for signed division by constant powers of 2.

(The range limit of n in `[0,30]` means that `1<<31` overflowing to `INT_MIN` is a non-issue.  I think this algorithm would work correctly for `n=31`, though.  The result is either `0` or `-1`, which are the two results possible for 32-bit `sar` by 31.  Adding `0x7fffffff` to any negative number other than `INT_MIN` = 0x80000000 will produce a non-negative number, so `sar` produces 0.  For x = INT_MIN, we're doing `-1 >> 31` giving `-1`.)

We can do `x + (1<<n)-1` and use the same test/cmovns gets us `x` or `x + (1<<n)-1`.  The `-1` part can be done as part of an LEA.

The most efficient way to get `1<<n` on Intel CPUs is with `bts` into a zeroed register.  (Variable-count `shl` is 3 uops, unless we use BMI2 `sarx`.  And materializing a `0` with xor is cheaper than `mov $1, %eax`.)  On AMD Zen where `bts` is 2 uops but `shl %cl, %eax` is only 1 (https://uops.info), it might be cheaper to move a `1` into EAX and `shl` that, since we need the shift count in CL anyway for the later `sar`.  (Unless we have BMI2 for `sarx` which allows the shift count to come from any register.)

Another option is to get `(1<<n) - 1` by applying [BMI2 `bzhi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bzhi) to `0xffffffff`; I think that works directly for `n` in the range `[0,32]` inclusive (although the `sar` still only works for n=[0,31]).  It's single-uop on Intel and AMD (https://uops.info/).  See below; that's what clang does for a C version of this.

```
# untested
.global dividePower2         # int x in EDI,  int n in ESI
                             # returns int in EAX
dividePower2:
   xor   %eax, %eax
   bts   %esi, %eax             # 2^n = 1<<n
   lea   -1(%rax, %rdi), %eax   # x + 2^n - 1

   test  %edi, %edi
   cmovns %edi, %eax     # x for non-negative,  x + 2^n - 1 for negative

   mov   %esi, %ecx      # or  sarx %esi, %eax, %eax
   sar   %cl, %eax       # >>= n  on the adjusted value is equivalent to /= (1>>n)
   ret
```

LEA with 3 components (`[-1 + rax + rdi]`) will have 3 cycle latency on Skylake and earlier, but Ice Lake runs it with 1 cycle latency.  "Slow" LEAs on Ice Lake and later can't run on as many ports, but don't have a latency penalty.  (On Alder Lake P-cores, *scaled* index costs 2 cycle latency like on Zen family, even when it's just a 2 component LEA, but we aren't scaling the index here.)  On Zen-family, this 3-component LEA has 2 cycle latency.  Same on Alder Lake E-cores.  So there'd be nothing to save by doing it with separate `add` and `dec` instructions.

Yet another way to get `(1<<n) - 1` is what older clang does: `0xffffffff >> (-n&31)`.  It actually generates `0xffffffff` or `0` from `sar $31, reg` to broadcast the sign bit.  But this strategy is less convenient for variable `n` because it would require a negation.  Especially inconvenient on x86 without BMI2 since shift counts need to be in CL.

---

A SIMD version of this with SSE2 `pslld` and `psrad` should be possible, or AVX2 `vpsllvd` with per-element variable counts.

Blending with SSE4.1 `pblendvps` is possible as a replacement for scalar `cmov`, but it seems like something more efficient should be possible. Perhaps more bithacky using `psrad` to get `0` or `-1` and do something with that?   Or just use that as a mask with `pandn` to zero out a `1<<n - 1` vector in elements where `x` was non-negative.  The `psrad` result is directly useful as a `-1` in `(1<<n) - 1`.

---

#### In C or C++

```
// well-defined behaviour for n=0..30
int divp2_bitshift(int x, int n){
    int bias = x < 0 ? (1U<<n)-1 : 0U;
    return (x+bias) >> n;
// To handle n=31, use  unsigned bias  and cast x+bias  back to signed int to avoid signed-overflow UB
// That might depend on int being 2's complement, so C++20 or C23
}

int divp2_reference(int x, int n){
    return x / (1LL<<n);  // 64-bit shift and division avoids overflow to INT_MIN
}
```

Clang `-march=skylake` compiles to optimized version in a clever way that uses `bzhi`:

```
# clang -O3 -march=skylake (BM1 and BMI2)
bitshift(int, int):
        movl    %edi, %eax
        sarl    $31, %eax            # 00000000 or FFFFFFFF
        bzhil   %esi, %eax, %eax     # 0 or (1<<n)-1 

        addl    %edi, %eax
        sarxl   %esi, %eax, %eax
        retq
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwBspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAOykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwc4QQA1MSYVPGMWxC7e6qkexcMyyaJVhoAgntvB5gEGwyXewD0ewgXBCIRMAGY3OC3HdwRY3n8AQFJABaGKEPb4ABueAyAhuCj2TD2tFQ%2BwUJIA7vE9niAJKCLp7OL8Q57WlbPYhJgAa0wJheDwAIvzniKLmiCAoEHgqARzoJLtdbvdHiL3jcFWimATwYLflC9ho9uCAGKArhyKFQu7Irh7ECGy1gp6vd6HL7EH4QVTWLUKZbGsHYcHYPYMWEi8xgmWGtXvC4U4hMFIpcLAAD6THQ6EDeogXgYGWAEXQy1UxssTLw2ojL3V6fTMS8dEcDEz2fTqEx8SolO91z913MAUTydTRnbpdh8IBmEICGpFKYAE89gBxNxuPYsHmYAkUkhKQkKFh7CnzsOoPZoYiHBwRBQE/BUY6HBgcggIJj7WnXwx7JQ%2BTrN1Pm%2BQFRxTNNJwDEMQzDWtRTMMFXBlSNEmFAUBSQmMNDFTUmnlfZVBVF11XdMDVD%2BIErQhLguHuZ00IwxDkIYZ9I0wljwmQbwsEDNwZnwVAADoEFgl4Lh3cIIHuAVVWA9U3hZQFblzQ1AzhcMITBMwNPgyxrBIuNFJM94CyLEsqwIFJvwIeIfl1WNGIU0yTPQVAHlI1zvJMi5DioNT/JOd9MAgCUbIIOzPWuGFnNdHyEo1fZUBSfZHIlKUZTlcLbPsmKGK8xKfJjCB/L2MAwEclKCBg%2BT4qKhq3hSYhdgCiBzDMFgcR3AhkCQCsAFYcwBaiIStMwhpgsE9XMIaBy8fYMulWU9mAUlBvQEwBuhDrSGMxqDoawjlhyyK8rDa5/OuaqCv2w6EvIz09i4BD7pMoU7oSoUKWleh2oMyxTqin4KscjRbpc9UPshkCPR%2BXC4uh54OFWWhOAG3g/A4LRSFQThIQBuEFHWTZMArMEeFIAhNBR1ZuRAMEAA5hIAThZgIWcSMEAjMLmkMZib9E4SRMZp3HOF4BQQA0KmadWOBYBgKAlYgJA0BYVN6DICgIHVzWRmALgdNILBsS2AA1PBMApAB5FJGE4SmaFoKKpbCsW0WYYhl0d3hPaaZcbZibRamp7heHVthBBthhaB97HeCwJtgDcMRaCl8OTcwHcjHEBOTbwO9HG7DOccwVRagW7ZKd2Lpff0PAYiTb2PCwMWCBalhfdWXsmGABRLetu2Hcz/hBBEMR2CkGRBEUFR1Hz3QuH0QxjGsawG5iKXIFWaqsgz5EbbBPZkQAdTTk%2Bd02MTprwLYDF5ZEeKthVkSoCDMV4Lt4harBt5kzo3QsguDYpMPwy9QjzHKJUPQhRMgCDAbA9I8CGCDGgSMZeNQ6gCD6BMTwbQ9BYJ6LguYZRhgJEwbMRBlD%2BhoPIRIVYxMNhbAYULDgGNSBYxxnjDglxGYBGREiVayBkDPTBMJXSEBcCEBIOTeivAw5aGWHTEAA0ZZow4CLUgXckTCW5pIRmOkuBmC4IzSQUhkhcK/hLWw0tZYJ3lirNWqANZ0HiOQSges3EJB4qvdMHcCzcizmbTAg9bb2yxk7Fs8Q3YxA9uEAO9d/beyDiHBw9dI6MAIDHOOYsk5eBTmnDOlMsA52AHnHG%2BAi54BLmLculc7L11rhoymtBG7N2XK3bYOMO54C7uHHuBh%2B5hOHpE3gY9hCiHENPCZc81Bi10GYFeRgUDr0sJvf%2Bu9Ur704IfY%2BZ8L7Iivn1XUChuTLgfmTN%2BH8v7dlvHgP%2B8BGFdFDsAiArhqHBDYnQxYFDUjIJ6J8uBPQfkwMwS87BvQqH4LyOCoBODZigowWMfonyZi0KgfQ%2BiaxmFT1RujUW%2BceF8IEUI3xRhAQBIYNyAMUj8BEGIHI5YCi5YqLUWwrRVjxYcElnYxRtM2FmF4F3RIkhhJSDBGCDQJjGYaACIzAaYIBqcLFjwllDjSAK0QCAdY1kFoeN1i4/WxBIisG2KofhgjJDCNEUbCRvBMD0pIA8vQEyJ7TOkLMpQ8zF56Agt3NhHCuU8JtgtFIC0aQBQtaS61wARFiIkYCDwritZMvVUo1YC4swjAARorRXcJrCQVQEDmiRGZcBZhTSQSIwQqqJTYqWMt%2BXKNIPTAIXBhIaA0FKwIYJEiBESO2xmbCwSEu4TY5t%2BKOBCrreOnl9iM2kDubiPwkggA), including a `main` to exhaustively test the reference version against the optimized version, for every `int32_t` bit-pattern and every `n` from `0` to `31`.  It passes for all cases.

With the reference implementation being `return x / (1<<n)`, it passes for all `n=0..30`, but fails for `-2147483648 / (1<<31) = 1` (because `1<<31` in the reference implementation overflows to INT_MIN, but the bit-shift version gives `-1` because it's dividing by a positive power of 2.)  I compiled with `gcc -O3 -fwrapv -march=native` to make signed integer overflow well-defined for ease of testing the asm.

So this optimization wouldn't be usable for `x/(1<<n)` with `gcc -fwrapv`, because the `n=31` behaviour is well-defined as having a negative divisor.

But without `-fwrapv` where signed overflow is undefined behaviour in C, this optimization would be valid.  TODO: report this missed-optimization to GCC and clang.

Also valid for `x/(1LL<<n)` for n=0..31, but not for n=32 or higher because that's still well-defined in C.  (I'm assuming x is a 32-bit `int`, so `long long` is wider; `n=32..63` are valid and make the quotient 0.)

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the IEEE standard of floating numbers in Computing.It will take up more memory but I dont see any other way.

Remember that any floating number can be written as :

s|exp bits|fraction bits

Let n1=x = s_x|exp bits_x|fraction bits_x

and n2=2^n 0|b(n+127)|0

n1/n2 will be simply equal to s_x|exp bits_x-b(n+127)|fraction bits_x

You will need 2 32-bit registers to store the divident and the divisor and 1 32-bit register for the result.

Comment: Now what?Where am I wrong now?

Comment: 32-bit `float` can't exactly represent all 32-bit integers, so just converting to `float` and back would introduce rounding error for inputs including `f(123456789, 0)`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values  Also, you haven't mentioned how to round back to an integer with `cvttss2si` to get truncation instead of the default rounding mode (nearest).  Using 64-bit `double`-precision FP could work, but I'd worry about rounding errors.  FP is certainly not the only way to do this.

Comment: It can go up to 2^128!

Comment: In C, it's literally just `return x / (1<<n);`.  Optimizing that to avoid `idiv` is fun, similar to how compilers optimize `x / 8` or other constant powers of 2. https://godbolt.org/z/qcaqbT9ah - compilers don't manage to optimize and do just use `idiv`.

Comment: Look the exponents bits are right?So it has values inside range of (0,255).Substract 127 from it,take the max(255) and you are left with 128.

Comment: Well at least my answer solves the part of if the number becomes smaller than 1.Then using a algorithm you can convert it to ASCII characters and print out the result.

Comment: It's not range that's the problem, it's precision in the upper part of the [0, 2^32) range.  I linked the section of the wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values) which points that out.  e.g. *Integers between 2^24 and 2^25 round to a multiple of 2 (even number)*.  And the rounding gets worse for larger integers. With only a 23-bit mantissa, it can't handle the precision of 32 significant digits. 32 bits can represent 2^32 different values.  For IEEE binary32, some of those values aren't integers in [0,2^32)

Comment: Re: your last comment: it appears the OP wants to do integer division, since they're showing the result from `f(-33, 4) = -2`, not `-2.0625`.  Also, float-to-ASCII algorithms are *very* hard to get right for every corner case.  Maybe not for cases that can result from integer divided by a power of 2 no greater than 2^30, though.  But fortunately we don't need an ASCII result, just a numeric variable.  e.g. a `double`, or the result of truncating one to integer.