# How to make the fastest compiled truncated counter in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, performance, loops, assembly

How to make a truncated counter that produces the fastest executing machine code on a modern x86 architecture?

**Own work :**

A naiive approach which I have long used for convenience is

```
i = (i+1)%MAX;
```

however this should be slow, because integer division is slow and also (as far as I know) it messes up the CPU instruction pipelines.

```
i++; i *= (i < MAX);
```

will require a multiplication which is not super fast, but less bad than division.

My best "bit twiddling" approach so far is quite ugly:

```
i |= (!(i+1==(MAX))-1); i++;
```

But with GCC -O3 optimization flag even the second approach seems to avoid mul and branch instructions by issuing instruction "cmove" (some kind of super fast conditional move)?

So... will it be worth investigating this any further and if so, how can it be done even better?

Comment: My advice is to not bother unless you have measured and benchmarked and profiled an optimized build to make sure that this is one of the top two (or possibly top three) bottlenecks in your program.

Comment: `if (++i == MAX) i = 0;`?

Comment: What @Evg says, even the branch predictor will not have a lot of problems with this. You might even give it a nudge (C++20) `if (++i == MAX) [[unlikely]] i = 0;`.

Comment: @Evg : your solution also produces a cmove instruction. Nice. I thought it would give a branch.

Comment: @OP are you using [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org)?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, that is how I found the cmove instruction being used with -O3.

Comment: Is `MAX` a compile time constant? And even better a power of two? Then the remainder operator `%` should be optimized to a bitmask operation.

Comment: @chrysante not always a power of two, but I agree with you. That is how I usually do it in that case.

Comment: Use a counter tthat match a max value equal to a power of two ... :p ... E.G. `i = (i++) & (128-1)`  ... ;)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: That is not your call. I have written high performance code where we optimized everything, including “little” items like this, with justifiable economic value. The question was asked and deserves an answer. The information is useful and ought to be mnown, and even just knowing it is useful for improving one’s software engineering ability generally. We should not be dissuading asking questions like this.

Comment: Branchless `cmov` becomes part of the critical path latency, which is bad if this is part of a very tight loop.  (Like in [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325)).  A cmp/jcc can be better, especially if `MAX` is large so the branch goes the same way almost all the time.  @EricPostpischil: Near duplicate of [Performance: Mod and assignment vs conditional and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52601216) although that one was tagged [x86] so my answer focuses on that.  This question is talking about x86 stuff like cmov, not AArch64 csinc.

Comment: This needs more context. E.g., could you also count from `MAX-1` down to zero, or from `-(MAX-1)` up to zero? Also, for very small `MAX` (and a small loop body) it can be best to completely unroll the loop.

Comment: @chrysante: That's only fully correct for `unsigned` types, or if the compiler can prove a signed `int` is non-negative.  `-5 % 4` is `-1`, vs. `-5 & 3` is `3`.  See [Divide by variable power of 2 using assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77449860) / https://godbolt.org/z/jnc1qModb - Compiler-generated asm for constant powers of 2 does involve `and`, but also multiple other instructions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK.

Comment: Can you do i++; i &= -(i < MAX);?

Comment: @SimonGoater yes it was something like that I had in mind. Even one less assembly instruction, it seems. Nice.

Comment: @SimonGoater: That just compiles to an x86 cmov or AArch64 csinc with GCC and clang (https://godbolt.org/z/1jennTfna), not an actual xor-zero / cmp/setcc / neg / AND, which would be worse so I wouldn't want to lead the compiler in the wrong direction with that bithack.  `i = i<MAX ? i : 0;` compiles efficiently.  It doesn't try to force branchless, but compilers choose that when appropriate for the target.  Can we get it down to just `cmp`/`csinc` on AArch64 without a separate `add` of 1?  Yes with diff. semantics for the limit, `return  i<limit ? i+1 : 0;` https://godbolt.org/z/9eT5eh5db

Comment: So if the caller passes the highest return value it wants to see, rather than the length, that simplifies things.  It also lets the x86 version do LEA in parallel with CMP for shorter critical-path latency.  If inlining into a loop, the compiler can hopefully adjust the limit by 1 if necessary either way you write it, unless that could introduce overflow/wrap-around where the abstract machine doesn't have any.

Comment: Shorter by 1 asm instruction compared to what? With gcc and clang -O3 for x86-64 and AArch64 (https://godbolt.org/z/GPK4zPoPo ),  Clang compiles all of your versions the same, even the bithack.  GCC sees through the multiply and turns it into `cmovle`, but does the bithack naively with 7 instructions (including `setcc`+`movzx` instead of xor-zeroing a register before cmp/setcc)